# Сделал автокликер с циклом while True:

Tags: python

Сделал автокликер на питоне с while true. При нажатии на определённую клавишу он включается, но как сделать его отключение по клавише?

Помогите пожалуйста! Использую модули mouse, keyboard, time, sleep

Comment: Без кода не о чем разговаривать. Но вообще подобные вопросы с ответами тут уже были, поищите

Answer (score 3):

отслеживай нажатие кнопки, если нажали выход из цикла

```
import keyboard  
while True:  
    ....
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
        break
```